# Value of optional type 'NSIndexPath?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this issue with my code, I think the problems appeared after my I changed syntax to new swift version.

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var FirstTableArray = [String]()
    var passThisArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // This array will display on your tableviewcell.
        FirstTableArray = [lib1]

        //You can pass element of this array
        passThisArray = ["1. Fi "]

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return FirstTableArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) 

        Cell.textLabel?.text = passThisArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        return Cell

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController

            //Get the Index of selected Cell
            let indexPath : IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            //assign string to next view controller instance from selected cell.
            vc.FirstString = FirstTableArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        }
    }
}
```

At this line it gives me 2 errors:

```
let indexPath : IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

1. > Value of optional type 'NSIndexPath?' not unwrapped; did you mean to
   >   use '!' or '?'?
2. > Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type
   >   'NSIndexPath?'

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no guarantee that the user has selected a row, so your call to `indexPathForSelectedRow` is an optional (it may or may not have a value).

A way to improve this method is to use the guard statement to safely unwrap the two optional values you have in this method. In the event that one of them is not set (nil), the method will safely exit without crashing your app.

One benefit of using guard over the `if let ...` approach is that you can avoid a pyramid of doom. Using your example, it would require three indents to run the final command where you assign the string, thus making your code harder to read. The guard statement is explicitly saying "if this value fails, guard against crashing".

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {
        guard let vc = segue.destination as? ViewController else {
            return
        }

        //Get the Index of selected Cell
        guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
            return
        }

        //assign string to next view controller instance from selected cell.
        vc.FirstString = FirstTableArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    }
}
```

Also, two minor code style musings:

- You do not need to use : NSIndexPath when you assign to `indexPath`. The compiler can infer the type for you
- When declaring variables, iOS convention is to use camelCase, so while your indexPath variable is good, you should change the `FirstString` to `firstString`

Comment: thank you very much, yes the guard statement was the solution.

Comment: Also thank you very much for the recommendations, yes I know about camelCase but at this case I think I followed a tutorial.

Comment: Now it gives me a breakpoint 1.5 to:     @IBOutlet var TextView: UITextView!
When I try to click an element on TableView.

Comment: @BeStar Probably not related, but something that got exposed once you worked past this error. Check your storyboard connection to make sure the linkage with your view controller is correct.